# Looping through a function that calls an API that pulls data into a variable till it returns nothing

Tags: python

This is the first script I have written in python so please bear with me as I learn.

I am writing a script that calls an API that then looks for expired certs and I have written a function that finds all certs expiring in x days. Now this works just fine if it's one cert but if there are multiple certs expiring they don't get outputted. I need to understand how I can store the information I need and pass it to the next function. I believe I need some kind of loop but don't fully understand how to store the information in a variable that can then be passed to the next function as it needs to be passed one at a time.

The cert_path variable is what gets passed to the next function as it tells that function where to look for the cert and downloads the certificate

```
def find_expiring_certificate():
    global cert_path, data, parse_json
    access_token = get_authorization()

    #Get date that is 31 days out
    #greater = datetime.today() + timedelta(days=31)
    #Testing
    greater = datetime.today() + timedelta(days=2000)
    format_greater_iso = greater.isoformat()

    
    url = "base_url/vedsdk/certificates?validtoless="+format_greater_iso+""
    payload = ""
    headers = {
    'Accept': 'applicaiton/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +access_token
    }

    response =  requests.request("Get", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

    #print(response.text)
    
    #parsing out the cert path
    data = response.text
    parse_json = json.loads(data)
    cert_path = parse_json['Certificates'][0]['DN']


    return(cert_path)
```

I have tried to loop the function but don't fully understand what I am doing nor know if that's the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

You're only returning the `DN` from the first certificate. You can use a list comprehension to return all of them.

```
cert_paths = [cert['DN'] for cert in parse_json['Certificates']]

return cert_paths
```

Comment: This works but it returns them all in a string which I am not sure how I can break it up so I can pass each individual result to the next function.

Comment: It doesn't return them in a string, it returns them all in a list.